# Get the value of runtime added controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

HTML

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="show" OnClick="show_Click" Text="show"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="add" OnClick="add_Click" Text="add new "/>
    <div id="content" runat="server"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

code

```
protected void show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(((CheckBox) content.FindControl("chb")).Checked);
}
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.ID = "chb";
    chb.Text = "chb";
    content.Controls.Add(chb);

}
```

by button `add` added a new `checkbox` on runtime.

then i want get checkbox `chb` by button `show`

but `((CheckBox) content.FindControl("chb")).Checked` return Null.

i want add checkbox dynamically and then checked that which of them checked is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your events don't happen in the same postback of your page - when you click `add`, it adds the checkbox but then the page execution finishes, the page is sent to the client and it's done with handling that `Click` event.

When you then click the `show` button, it's another postback, in which your checkbox has not been created, so it doesn't exist.

To handle this, you have a few options:

1.
Add the checkbox to the page in the designer and set its `Visible` property to `false` inially. You can keep the `add` button, but it won't actually add a checkbox to the page, it'll just make it visible by setting `Visible` to `true`.

2.
If you really want to dynamically add the checkbox, then you need to add it every time the page is executed, in one of the page event handlers (for example `Load`). The way to do that is to save a value in the viewstate or in a hidden field when you click `add` and based on the value, you'd create the checkbox on subsequent postbacks.

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( IsPostBack )
    {
        if ( Session["chb"] != null )
            CreateChb ();
    }
}
protected void show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(((CheckBox) content.FindControl("chb")).Text);
}
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["chk"] = true;
    CreateChb ();
}
private void CreateChb ()
{
    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.ID = "chb";
    chb.Text = "chb";
    content.Controls.Add(chb);
}
```

Comment: i want add checkbox dynamically and then checked that which of them checked is true

Comment: If you want to maintain the state of the checkbox, you'd be much better off creating the checkbox control in the designer and showing it/hiding it when needed. You can do this dynamically but you'll have to basically preserve the state of the dynamic control yourself which will be a lot of work. If you plan on adding more than one control dynamically, you'll have to do that work for all of them. Why do you want to add controls dynamically?

Comment: If you really plan on adding 100 checkboxes to a page this way, you're in for some serious work - unless you really, really need to do it that way, it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because dynamically added controls are not preserved after postbacks. You can easily demonstrate this by adding another button (without a click event handler) to the page. Run the application and click the "add" button to create the checkbox, then click the newly added button and the checkbox will be gone after the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can not understand what you are trying to achieve but;

```
  protected void show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        Response.Write((Session["chb"] as CheckBox).Text);
    }
    protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.ID = "chb";
        chb.Text = "chb";
        content.Controls.Add(chb);
        Session["chb"] = chb;

    }
```

Comment: Your example works but I don't think it's a very good idea to keep controls in the session. (Although I personally don't think it's a good idea to dynamically add controls other than in a few scenarios. :)  )

Comment: @xxbbcc You are right, but as I told in my answer I did not understand the purpose.

Comment: @user1263390 if you are building an application for 2000 users, I may simply say you are in the wrong way of handling such situations. But it seems your code is not like a real application but more than a trial.

Comment: yes. i does not 2000 user but i want understand how can do this.by a good way